# Defining particular sub-groups in survival analysis in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survminer

This is the code in R that produces a Kaplan-Meier plot of Overall Survival for a population broken down by Stage.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(forcats)
library(broom)
library(survival)
library(Hmisc)
library(gmodels)
library(lazyeval)
library(plotrix)
library(summariser)
library(magrittr)
library(survminer)
library(dplyr)
library(lattice)
library(Formula)
library(lubridate)
library(ggfortify)
library(readxl)

icccdata = read_excel("ICCC_All_20072016.xls")
head(icccdata)
km <- with(icccdata, Surv(Time, Status))

# STAGE specific OVERALL SURVIVAL
survival_object2 <- Surv(icccdata$Time, icccdata$CancerSurvival)
str(survival_object2)
my_survfit_STAGE_OS <- survfit(survival_object2 ~ Stage, data = icccdata)
print(my_survfit_STAGE_OS, print.rmean = TRUE)
dat_my_survfit_STAGE_OS <- fortify(my_survfit_STAGE_OS)
ggsurvplot(my_survfit_STAGE_OS, risk.table = TRUE, xlab = "Time (years)", censor = T)
```

The Stage data consists of the values 0, I, II, III, IV.

I want to be able to just show the values for Stage I, without having the Stage 0, II, III, or IV displayed. I'd appreciate some help with the code to separate out a single sub-group.

A

Comment: How about subsetting the data before calculating the Kaplan-Meier estimator, such as `icccdata_stage0 <- subset(icccdata, Stage=="0"); survival_object2_stage0 <- Surv(icccdata_stage0$Time, icccdata_stage0$CanserSurvival); ...`?

Comment: Do you really need all those libraries to run this snippet of code?

Comment: @CaptainHat you are correct, but I don't really know how many I do need, and coding efficiency is not my forte. Coding is not my forte, I spend most of my time trying to get things to work.

Comment: yh6, thank you for the suggestion, I will look to see how to use your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building your own `ggplot()` instead of using `ggsurvplot()`.
This can be done by using `surv_summary()` from the `survminer` package. This is also what `ggsurvplot()` is using behind the scenes.

E.g.:

```
df <- surv_summary(my_survfit_STAGE_OS)
df %>% filter(Stage == "I") %>% 
       ggplot(aes(x = time, y = surv, col = Stage)) + 
       geom_step()
```

If you want to plot stage I and II you could use `%in%` like

```
df %>% filter(Stage %in% c("I", "II")) %>% ggplot(....)
```

In `ggsurvplot()` a dataframe from `surv_summary()` is passed to `ggsurvplot_df()` and then created using `ggplot()` based on user options.
Check out the R source code here:
https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/blob/master/R/ggsurvplot_df.R

If you want an at risk table this can be created using `ggrisktable()`

Comment: Michael, thanks for the work. I'll get working on the changes.